# mvc multi image upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a model like :

```
public class CarpetM
{
   public long ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and my view for add new carpet is like:

```
@model MVC_WebApp.Models.CarpetM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ManageLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create New Carpet</h2>


    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">


             <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" multiple />
             <div id="images_prev">


              </div>



         </div>

         <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
        </div>

}
```

I want to select multi image for one carpet and save them according to carpet's `ID` to `CarpetsImages` path on server, so I add the java-script code below to my view file:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        var image_index = 1;

        var loadFile = function (event) {

            for (i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
                $('#images_prev').prepend('<img width="150px" height="220px" src="' + URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[i]) + '" /><input type="hidden" name="img' + image_index.toString() + '" value="' + event.target.files[i] + '"/>');
            }

        };
    </script>
    }
```

and mu controller action is :

```
 public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,Name")] CarpetM carpetm)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Carpets.Add(carpetm);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }


            return View(carpetm);
        }
```

Now : how can I save selected images in client browser to my server directory? How can I get images on above action?

Comment: Give your file a `name` attribute (say `name="files"` and add a parameter to you POST method (or a property to your model) - `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files`

Comment: thenks,i do it but no file are passed to my parameter ,my action is like bellow: public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] CarpetM carpetm, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files) and my input changed to :<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)" multiple name="files" />

Comment: You also need to add the `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` attribute to the `<form>` element

Comment: ok,my goal is that after selecting some images i show user preview of them and user can remove or add another ,so the above solution not work fine and just upload last selection images

Comment: That's because of your script!

Comment: help me to correct that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88183/discussion-between-hossein-ab-and-stephen-muecke).